# Multiple connections on the same boost tcp socket object

Tags: c++, boost, boost-asio

In this [example(async_tcp_echo_server.cpp)](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_54_0/doc/html/boost_asio/example/cpp11/echo/async_tcp_echo_server.cpp),

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
#include <utility>
#include <boost/asio.hpp>

using boost::asio::ip::tcp;

class session
  : public std::enable_shared_from_this<session>
{
public:
  session(tcp::socket socket)
    : socket_(std::move(socket))
  {
  }

  void start()
  {
    do_read();
  }

private:
  void do_read()
  {
    auto self(shared_from_this());
    socket_.async_read_some(boost::asio::buffer(data_, max_length),
        [this, self](boost::system::error_code ec, std::size_t length)
        {
          if (!ec)
          {
            do_write(length);
          }
        });
  }

  void do_write(std::size_t length)
  {
    auto self(shared_from_this());
    boost::asio::async_write(socket_, boost::asio::buffer(data_, length),
        [this, self](boost::system::error_code ec, std::size_t /*length*/)
        {
          if (!ec)
          {
            do_read();
          }
        });
  }

  tcp::socket socket_;
  enum { max_length = 1024 };
  char data_[max_length];
};

class server
{
public:
  server(boost::asio::io_service& io_service, short port)
    : acceptor_(io_service, tcp::endpoint(tcp::v4(), port)),
      socket_(io_service)
  {
    do_accept();
  }

private:
  void do_accept()
  {
    acceptor_.async_accept(socket_,
        [this](boost::system::error_code ec)
        {
          if (!ec)
          {
            std::make_shared<session>(std::move(socket_))->start();
          }

          do_accept();
        });
  }

  tcp::acceptor acceptor_;
  tcp::socket socket_;
};

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
  try
  {
    if (argc != 2)
    {
      std::cerr << "Usage: async_tcp_echo_server <port>\n";
      return 1;
    }

    boost::asio::io_service io_service;

    server s(io_service, std::atoi(argv[1]));

    io_service.run();
  }
  catch (std::exception& e)
  {
    std::cerr << "Exception: " << e.what() << "\n";
  }

  return 0;
}
```

multiple sessions are using the same `boost::ip::tcp::socket` object. Inside `do_accept()` function, upon every incoming connection we are creating a new session object and passing `socket_` to it by rvalue reference i.e. by `std::move()`.

Let's say we have two connections (S1 and S2) which are active. The structure will roughly look like this

```
                           Server
                             |
                             |_ socket_
                                  /\
                                 /  \
                                /    \
                               S1    S2
```

So both S1 and S2 will be using the same `socket_` to read/write messages from/to the network.

I have two questions about this:

1. For the first connection everything is fine, but why is the second connection supposed to work all right? Haven't we already transferred the ownership of `socket_` to the first session?
2. How is it ensured that reply is being sent to the correct client? Whenever something arrives on the socket, can't any one of the two `async_read_some` get triggered?

Comment: I recommend you take a step back from Boost ASIO and other frameworks or abstractions of sockets and network programming, and take some time to learn how sockets works below these frameworks. If you to that you should quite quickly learn that accepting an incoming connection on a passive listening TCP socket will create a *new* socket for the connection. The passive listening socket only listen for incoming connections, nothing more. Once you know how things work beneath the frameworks and abstractions, you will be better equipped to use the frameworks.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude So isn't acceptor analogous to passive listening TCP socket and tcp::socket analogous to active socket? In other similar examples, we have one socket each for every connection/session.

Comment: Yes those are equivalent. And note that the `acceptor_.async_accept` call takes a reference to the `tcp::socket` as its first argument, and that it initializes that socket with the new accepted connection socket.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude But what happens in case of a second connection, as we are using the same socket in all connections? So upon second connection, the `tcp::socket` argument will get reinitialized with second connection data socket, but the first connection was already using it to read/write.

Comment: No, the `async_accept` function will call the lower-level `accept` function to create a new socket for the connection. This new socket will be used to ***initialize*** the `tcp::socket` object. No matter how many connections are accepted, the `tcp::socket` object will always be initialized as a new socket.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> For the first connection everything is fine, but why is the second connection supposed to work all right? Haven't we already transferred the ownership of socket_ to the first session?

After moving from the socket, the socket happens to be essentially "empty" or "newly created". That's why this works.

And no, the socket object does not "magically" share identity with the moved instances. In fact, the identity is little more than the underlying socket handle, which is obviously not shared.

> But what happens in case of a second connection, as we are using the same socket in all connections?

You're not. You're not using the same socket handle. Neither are you using the same `asio::ip::tcp::socket` object instance.